# vtable error in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I have included my custom framework to a sample application made for phonegap for making a custom plugin.

At compile time i am getting following error:

Undefined symbols for architecture i386:

"vtable for _*cxxabiv1::*_class_type_info", referenced from:
      typeinfo for z_stream_s in FrameworkName(zlibengn.o)

NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

What this error means? and, How we can resolve it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved the problem. I have just added -lstdc++ to my other linker flags in build settings and errors gone.

Comment: Thank you very much for coming back and sharing your solution! Worked for me too...

Comment: Does this happen only in Swift project?